# I need to do a specific thing depending on Type, not sure how to implement it

Tags: c#, generics, .net-core, casting, c#-8.0

I have been building a consumer where each message comes with a SchemaType which is a AssemblyQualifiedName and also a Payload which is the object of this type.

In order to cast it I have come up with this:

```
Type innerType = Type.GetType(values["SchemaType"]);
Type eventWithInnerType = typeof(Event<>).MakeGenericType(new[] { innerType });
var @event = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(messageBody, eventWithInnerType);
```

Now I should take a different action depending on innerType. But I am quite stuck, not sure what would be the best approach to do so.

For example: innerType could be to call a service that sends an email, next message could be to call a service to persist something into the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Version 1:**

Defining a set of overload `ProcessEvent()` which take various `Event<T>`, varying the `T`, sounds like a good idea to me.

```
ProcessEvent(Event<DbQuery> evt);
ProcessEvent(Event<ServiceCall> evt);
```

**Version 2:**

Short of that, if your `T` contains an `EventType` which you can surface through `Event<T>.EventType`, a switch expression may be the next best thing.

```
var outcome = evt.EventType switch
{
    EventType.DbCall => CallDatabase(evt),
    EventType.CallService => CallService(evt),
    // so forth
};
```

Comment: Great insight! Turns out I implemented it using a factory to decide which service should be created based on the mesage type.